# Estimate for Sobolev Norm

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

> We have
> \begin{equation}
>     L u=\sum_{i, j=1}^n \partial_i\left(a_{ij} \partial_j u\right)
> \end{equation}
> and $u$ a solution of the weak Dirichlet problem
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> L u=f \text { weakly in } \Omega, \\
> u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) .
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> I want to show
> $$
> \|u\|_{W^{1,2}} \leq \rho\left(\operatorname{diam}(\Omega)+\operatorname{diam}(\Omega)^2\right)\|f\|_{L^2},
> $$
> where $\rho$ is the ellipticity constant of $L$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Testing the equation with $u$ should give
$$ \rho^{-1} \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 \le \|f\|_{L^2} \|u\|_{L^2}
\le  \|f\|_{L^2} \cdot diam(\Omega) \|\nabla u\|_{L^2},$$
which is almost the desired inequality.

Comment: Took the weak formulation of your pde, and used $u$ itself as test function. Then used ellipticity and Hoelder inequality.